# Error happens when I call a method in an other class

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have an error when I'm trying to call a method in an other class. The error is :

> 'Chaise[]' does not contain a definition for 'fabricationbois' and no
>   extension method 'fabricationbois' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Chaise[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Actually, I'm calling this method by this way :

```
Chaise[] chair = new Chaise[this.actual+1];

Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(chair.fabricationbois));
```

The error happens on `chair.fabricationbois`.

My method is :

```
public override void fabricationbois()
{
   //do something
}
```

I don't understand because the method in the class Chaise exists and I can create the object, so why I can't call this method ?

Comment: You're calling `fabricationbois` on _an array_ of `Chaise` objects, not on a `Chaise` object itself.  To get a proper answer, can you clarify what you're trying to do?  Start a new thread for each element in the array perhaps?

Comment: Are you intentionally allocating an array?

Comment: Try to use one element from your chair array

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, the user can choose the number of chairs that he wants and with that variable, I want an array of chair. But to create the chair, I need several steps, and this steps are in some threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chair` is an array of `Chaise`. You should select an element in array

```
var selectedChair = chair[0]; // you are selecting an element.
Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(selectedChair .fabricationbois));
```

If you want to have a thread for each element you can do it like below

```
var threads = chair.Select(x => new Thread(new ThreadStart(x.fabricationbois)))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, I need to specify the exact element of my array ! It works now, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You must select one element from your array

```
Chaise[] chair = new Chaise[this.actual+1];
/// Let's suppose here you fill your array with elements
Chaise firstChair = chair[0]; // Here I select the first chair
if(firstChair != null)
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(firstChair.fabricationbois));
```

Comment: Asuming `Chaise` is a `class` type, `chair[0]` will definitely be `null` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Mention index for the list like chair[0].

Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(chair[0].fabricationbois));